# auto grow SQL 2008 in relationship to file groups

Tags: sql

I am moving some indexes\tables to a secondary file group. What are the ideal settings on the DB in question in regards to the 'Auto Grow' options after the tables moves ?

Answer (score 0):

The usual recommendation is to manually pre-size the database files rather than relying on auto grow (but to leave auto grow on in case you guessed wrong).  Aside from that, "ideal" depends on your database, how big it is, how quickly it's growing, etc.